# How can I replace multiple elements in a list in python

Tags: python, list, replace

I am writing a program in python and I have currently this:

```
settings[4] = quote_bg.get()
settings[5] = quote_fg.get()
```

Is there any way I can do that in only one line because I have to add more of them (in order)
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `settings[4], settings[5] = quote_bg.get(), quote_fg.get()`?

Comment: What's your full program? What are you trying to add together? [Can you produce a minimal reproducable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: its a simple program with tkinter

Comment: @Samwise yeah, that works, thanks. Do you have any idea for the first part? How to make that shorter? I have tried settings[4:5] but it did not work

Comment: If you have a bunch of settings you could do it in a loop.  I suspect that with more context an overall simpler approach would suggest itself.

Comment: There's no point to just doing it in one line.  What are you really trying to do?  You said _I have to add more of them (in order)_.  Can you go ahead and show us what that might look like?...even if it's painful or not what you want it to ultimately look like, so that we can get an idea of what exactly you're trying to avoid or accomplish.  There's likely something you can do that's more efficient, but asking to do this in one line is what's called an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could write :

```
settings = ['', '', '', '', quote_bg.get(), quote_fg.get()]
```

or for better clarity :

```
settings = [
    '', # this is settings[0]
    '',
    '',
    '',
    quote_bg.get(), # settings[4]
    quote_fg.get(), # settings[5]
    ...
]
```

if the other list member does not need to be updated and that your `quote_xx.get()` calls populate `settings` from 4 to n, you can

```
settings = ['', '', '', ''] # settings[0] to [3] 
settings.append(quote_bg.get()) # [4]
settings.append(quote_fg.get()) # [5]
```

or in one line :

```
settings.extend( [quote_bg.get(),quote_fg.get()] ) # [4] and [5]
```

a bit more experimental, fyi, you could reference the function itself in the list, then call it to update/display the value :

```
settings[4] = quote_bg.get # no (), this is not run yet, this is the function object
...
settings[4]() # at some point to update
```

Ani is right, you should give a bit more context in your question to know wether you need a `for`loop or not.

The [python doc about containers](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) would help you a lot.